# Disable Fabric answers in debug mode

Tags: ios, twitter-fabric

I use Fabric framework together with Crashlytics and Twitter dependencies. Is it possible to turn off only statistic which Fabric generates in Answers tab? There are many sessions with simulator so analytics aren't precise then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to turn off Answers, just deselect the **checkbox** for your app in the Fabric Mac App (see attached screenshot).

If you want to get user stats for Answers when you release your app, then you could have another app on Fabric and only use those keys in your production build.

[image: Fabric Mac App]

Comment: you are right. I created two fabric apps. One for testing and one for production mode

Comment: Hi Shantanu, can you please provide more details on, how can I set two different answer framework with a different key for debug and release mode?

Answer (score 0):

I've added an adapter module with the such methods:

```
#if DEBUG
func logContentView(name: String, type: String, id: String? = nil) {
    print("Content view \"\(name)\" of type \"\(type)\" with id \"\(id ?? "null")\"")
}
#else
import Crashlytics

func logContentView(name: String, type: String, id: String? = nil) {
    Answers.logContentView(withName: name, contentType: type, contentId: id)
}
#endif
```

In view controllers I log events in the following way:

```
logContentView(name: "Main", type: "Screen")
```

Thus my app doesn't generate events in debug builds.